# Удаления из ArrayList<Character> элементов массива char[]

Tags: java, массивы, arraylist, char

У меня есть два массива:

```
char[] mainLain = userInput.toCharArray();
char[] exp = enteringException.toCharArray();
```

Массив `mainLain` копируется в `ArrayList<Character>` :

```
ArrayList< Character> mainLainClone = userInput.chars().mapToObj(x -> (char) x).collect(toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

В `char[] exp` находятся символы, которое мне нужно удалить из `mainLainClone`.

Я пытаюсь это сделать вот так:

```
mainLainClone.removeAll(Collections.singleton(Arrays.toString(exp)));
```

Но ничего не удаляется из `mainLainClone`. Какие есть способы, это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Есть очень простой способ перебора элементов с двойным `for`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < mainLainClone.size(); i++) {
        for (char c : exp) {
            if (mainLainClone.get(i) == c) {
                mainLainClone.remove(i);
            }
        }
    }
```